# Are there any limitations for the FCM topics names?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to find out if there are any limitations for the topic names for FCM. Managed to find info about the number of topics (no limitations), but nothing like length of topic name or allowed characters.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, not all characters are allowed, having space between words is not allowed in topic names.

From the docs:

> sending messages to a Firebase Cloud Messaging topic is very similar to sending messages to an individual device or to a user group. The app server sets the topic key in the message body with a value like `yourTopic`. Developers can choose any topic name that matches the regular expression: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+"

for more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging (build request section)

Comment: BTW only 900 signs are allowed: decompiled pattern matcher of androids `com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging` class: `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}")`

Comment: I think Push IDs can be used as Topic IDs? Right?

Comment: Small update, more info is here now https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics-legacy

Comment: Topic names can optionally be prefixed with `"/topics/"`, but this prefix is not checked as part of the regex `"[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}"`

Answer (score 1):

Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic. However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:
One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.
The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there are limitations on *FCM topic names*.
**FCM topic** must match the following regular expression: `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}`.